# Sandy-Bridge CPU specification

Tags: cpu, intel, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I was able to put together bits here and there about the Sandy Bridge-E architecture but I am not totally sure about all the parameters e.g. the size of the L2 cache. Can anyone please confirm they are all correct? My main source was the [64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On sandy bridge, each core has 256KB of L2 ([see the datasheet, section 1.1](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/core-i7-lga-2011-datasheet-vol-1.html)). for 6 cores, that's 1.5MB, but since each core only accesses its own, it's better to always look at it as 256KB per core.

Moreover, the peak gflops looks completely wrong. AVX is 16 flops/cycle (as single floats). with 6 cores, that's ~307 gflops/s at 3.2GHz.

Most of the rest of the data looks ok (looking at the datasheet and the [specification of that model](http://ark.intel.com/products/63697/Intel-Core-i7-3930K-Processor-%2812M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz%29) in particular), though I don't know for sure the associativity of each cache.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually indeed the peak-performance was very wrong. I am looking at single threaded so it is 24 Gflops = 3Ghz * 8 AVX double instructions per cycle.

Comment: Actually Sandy Bridge AVX is 16 F32 flop/cycle and 8 F64 flop/cycle. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15657772/1762344

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk: well, that's embarrassing. Thanks.